# is it possible to clear the javascript or css to a particular section or div

Tags: javascript, html, css

if i have an html code like below:

```html
  <section class="services page-spy" id="services">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- Start Mobile Slider Content-->
          <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 order-lg-7 order-md-12 rotate-inner wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="1s">
            <div class="rotate-content">
              <!-- Start Slider Links-->
              <ul class="nav nav-pills mobile-nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="active-icon" data-owl-item="0"><a href="#tab_a" data-toggle="pill"><i class="lni-support"></i></a></li>
                <li data-owl-item="1"><a href="#tab_b" data-toggle="pill"><i class="lni-cloud-download"></i></a></li>
                <li data-owl-item="2"><a href="#tab_c" data-toggle="pill"><i class="lni-bar-chart"></i></a></li>
                <li data-owl-item="3"><a href="#tab_d" data-toggle="pill"><i class="lni-world"></i></a></li>
                <li data-owl-item="4"><a href="#tab_e" data-toggle="pill"><i class="lni-mobile"></i></a></li>
                <li data-owl-item="5"><a href="#tab_f" data-toggle="pill"><i class="lni-gallery"></i></a></li>
                <li data-owl-item="6"><a href="#tab_g" data-toggle="pill"><i class="lni-user"></i></a></li>
                <li data-owl-item="7"><a href="#tab_h" data-toggle="pill"><i class="lni-bulb"></i></a></li>
                <li data-owl-item="8"><a href="#tab_i" data-toggle="pill"><i class="lni-cog"></i></a></li>
                <li data-owl-item="9"><a href="#tab_j" data-toggle="pill"><i class="lni-link"></i></a></li>
                <li data-owl-item="10"><a href="#tab_k" data-toggle="pill"><i class="lni-layers"></i></a></li>
                <li data-owl-item="11"><a href="#tab_l" data-toggle="pill"><i class="lni-anchor"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
              
              </div>
              </div>
              
              </div>
              
              </section>
```

and if i have some files to apply javascript or css like below

```html
<script src="test/app.js"></script>
     <script src="test/plugins.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

like if all the sections or div are already styled in the css file,
is it possible not to apply the css or javascript in a particular section or div , over riding the styles and scripts only for that section?

Comment: Yes, you can try out using element id.

Comment: @ManishKhedekar  like and example can you show?

Comment: @ZubairShah I am not certain you have provided as much context needed to be able to respond to this question. Is there an event that should trigger the removal of the styles or scripts you have for that part of your markup or is it on page load?

Comment: @zubair-shah if you think my answer helped you please accept it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally include your js and css file like so:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('your_element_class');

if (element)
{
  // Do nothing if element exists with class
}
else
{
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

  var js = document.createElement("script");
  js.type = "text/javascript";  
  js.src = "your_script.js";  
  head.appendChild(js);

  var css = document.createElement("link");
  css.type = "text/css";  
  css.href = 'your_styles.css';
  css.rel = 'stylesheet';
  head.appendChild(css);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the javascript behavior of a DOM element you can affect the behavior/action to a class add the class to your element and remove the class of the element for some cases

Here is an example to do that : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_class.asp

Tell me if it is what you need

Answer (score 0):

You may try out like,

```js
let classes = ['red', 'blue', 'black', 'tomato', 'cornflowerblue'];
let counter = 0;

function toggleClass(){
  if(counter < classes.length){
    document.getElementById('div1').style.backgroundColor = classes[counter];
    document.getElementById('div2').style.backgroundColor = classes[counter];
    document.getElementById('div3').style.backgroundColor = classes[counter];
    
    counter++;
  }else{
    counter = 0;
    toggleClass();
  }
}
```

```css
#div1{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

#div2{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#div3{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>


<button id="btn" onclick="toggleClass()">Change Color Class</button>
```

Above is the example of dynamic inline styling.
You can have css classes of your own and can add and remove them with the element context;
For adding and removing CSS classes, you can try as,

```
// Adding CSS class
document.getElementById('div1').classList.add("mystyle");

// Removing CSS class
document.getElementById('div1').classList.remove("mystyle");
```

Here 'mystyle' would be a CSS class,

```
.mystyle {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
 }
```